# Getting indices out of index buffer

Tags: c++

I have an array of indices
faces
how would I loop and get each index ?

```
for (int n = 0 ; n < updatedIndices.size(); n++)
        {
            int n0 = updatedIndices[n+0];
            int n1 = updatedIndices[n+1];
            int n2 = updatedIndices[n+2];

            manual->triangle(n0, n1, n2);

        }
```

but this crashes
because when n == updated.size()
updatedIndices will be out of bounds
I know its very basic
but how would I solve it ?

Comment: `n < updatedIndices.size() - 2`?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash because the loop body is not entered when `n == updatedIndices.size()`. There is another problem, try to find it. Hint: Why do you need a loop?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I have a lot of indices that I need to draw, and ogre needs the indices to be defined

Comment: yes keep negating my question, instead of tell me why !!

Comment: @andreahmed _"instead of tell me why !"_ You were already told why. What do you think that `[n+1]` or `[n+2]` refers to if `n` equals `updatedIndices.size() - 1` or ``updatedIndices.size() - 2``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code crashes because you're trying to access index that is out of range. Simply loop through all-but-2 items:

```
for (int n = 0; n < updatedIndices.size() - 2; n++)
```